# OpenFire in SharedHosting or VPS

Tags: xmpp, vps, openfire, shared-hosting

I've set up openfire successfully in my home pc (vm) and it can be connected to from any where over internet.
But, using home pc as a chat server is not at all convenient and hence I am looking for alternatives.

Is it possible to install openfire on a shared hosting service say of [this](https://in.godaddy.com/pro/cpanel-hosting) kind OR it needs a VPS to install openfire like [this](https://in.godaddy.com/pro/managed-vps).

In each of the cases, what are the pros-and-cons ?

Comment: yes you can install in shared hosting

Comment: Can it be used for production purpose from a shared hosting [Performance wise] ? And any associated pros and cons ?

Comment: If focusing on performance and customization it is better to use VPS,VPS is just like a dedicated server with full root access.

Answer (score 1):

It works on Shared hosting, but it is not recommended. Most of the shared hosting companies have already built-in tools to limit your access to server resources and you will observe poor performance on shared hosting.

I will recommend to install OpenFire on an [ideal hosting combination like LiteSpeed Web Server, SSD Hosting and CloudFlare OS](https://www.accuwebhosting.com/blog/2014/12/04/ideal-linux-hosting-cloudlinux-litespeed-ssd-storage/%20ideal%20hosting%20combination%20like%20LiteSpeed%20Web%20Server,%20SSD%20Hosting%20and%20CloudFlare%20OS) ...

[VPS like this](https://www.accuwebhosting.com/vps-hosting/linux-vps-hosting/vps-ssd) will give ultimate performance with minimum hardware resources.